# How to aggregate character data by assigning weights to them in SAS Enterprise Guide or SAS PROC SQL?

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql, enterprise-guide, 4gl

I have Table in SAS Enterprise Guide like below.

Data type:

- ID - numeric
- GROUP - character (only PRI or CON values)

| ID | GROUP |
| --- | --- |
| 8945 | CON |
| 9567 | PRI |
| 9567 | PRI |
| 284 | CON |
| 284 | CON |
| 284 | PRI |

And I need to create new character column "COL1" where:

- If even once a given ID is in the PRI group, no matter how many times it was in CON COL1 = PRI
- if ID is nowhere PRI only CON, then CON

Generally, PRI is more important group than CON, and if you was at least once in PRI gropu, you have PRI in new COL1. So, as a result I need somethin like below:

| ID | COL1 |
| --- | --- |
| 8945 | CON |
| 9567 | PRI |
| 284 | PRI |

How can I do that in SAS Enterprise Guide in PROC SQL or in normal SAS code ?

Comment: So, if COL1 is PRI, and at least once GROUP was CON, then in resulting table you have CON?

Comment: PRI is more important than CON -> So, if you had at least one time PRI in GROUP for some ID, then PRI in COL1 and nevermind how many time you had CON in GROUP, if you have never had PRI in GROUP then COL1 = CON for that ID (GROUP variables has only PRI or CON) - do you understand Negdo? :)

Comment: I get what happens with COL1. I have problems with column GROUP. Unless you don't join IDs into one line (like you did in your resulting table)

Comment: Yes, you are right, in output table should not be GROUP column, I am sorry, I edited my utput :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
data have;
input ID GROUP $;
datalines;
8945 CON
9567 PRI
9567 PRI
284  CON
284  CON
284  PRI
;

proc sql;
   create table want as
   select distinct * 
   from have
   group by ID
   having whichc(GROUP, 'PRI', 'CON') 
    = min(whichc(GROUP, 'PRI', 'CON'));
quit;
```

Comment: PeterClemmensen, it works perfetcly! Thank you very much, I gave you best answer :)